# would mysql js pool cause transaction deadlock

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am designing an ticket system using NodeJS and Mysql-Promise.
For safety and consistency, I want to use Transaction but I worry about the deadlock.
The scenario is

> 1. People can buy multi tickets in one order
> 2. I would check every tickets whether the rest amount of tickets is enough or not.
> 3. I update the amount of tickets
> 4. I create the order

The code is

```
        await ctx.conn.beginTransaction()

        // check amount of tickets
        let ticketIdList = ctx.body.tickets.map(t => t._id)
        let ticketList = await models.ticket.findTicketList(ctx.conn, ticketIdList)
        for (let t in ticketList) {
            let ticketBook = ctx.body.tickets.filter(tB => tB._id === t._id)
            if (t.perMinSaleCount > ticketBook.count || t.perMaxSaleCount < ticketBook.count) {
                ctx.stats = 400
                return ctx.body = {
                    error: "FailTickets"
                }
            }
            if (t.sold + ticketBook.count > t.total) {
                ctx.stats = 400
                return ctx.body = {
                    error: "SoldOut"
                }
            }
        }

        // update the tickets
        await Promise.all(
            ctx.body.tickets.map(t => models.ticket.reserveTicket(ctx.conn, t._id, t.count))
        )

        // create Order
        await model.order.createOrder(...)

        await ctx.conn.commit()
```

My big concern is the ctx.conn is create by pool

```
mysql.createPool({
        ......
    })
```

Would `// await Promise.all(ctx.body.tickets.map(t => models.ticket.reserveTicket(ctx.conn, t._id, t.count)))` this lines make sql in multi connections and cause deadlock ?
How to properly use `conn.beginTransaction()`?

Thanks

Comment: You can't avoid deadlocks. They happen and it's a normal occurrence in concurrent environment. You can only react to deadlocks by repeating transactions for a few times, then giving up if it really won't budge.

Comment: My concern is whether `Promise.all(conn)` run in multi connection and make sql into multi transaction because of pool?